# OpenCV: rotating video frames

Tags: c++, opencv, rotation, yuv

I am trying to rotate video frames captured using `libcamera-vid` from [libcamera-apps](https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera-apps) an arbitrary amount of degrees using OpenCV's [warpAffine()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga0203d9ee5fcd28d40dbc4a1ea4451983).

The frames are as far as I can understand on yuv420 planar format.

The gist of what I'm doing is:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

cv::Point2f Ycenter = cv::Point2f(width / 2.0f, height / 2.0f);
cv::Point2f UVcenter = cv::Point2f(width / 4.0f, height / 4.0f);
double rotation = 0;
cv::Mat Ytransform = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(Ycenter, rotation, 1.0);
cv::Mat UVtransform = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(UVcenter, rotation, 1.0);

int Uoffset = height*width;
int Voffset = 5*info.height*info.width/4;

cv::Size Ysize(info.height, info.width);
cv::Size UVsize(info.height / 2, info.width / 2);

for (unsigned int count = 0; ; count++)
{
    // ...
    // Wait for frame here
    // ...    
    
    // Acquire buffer in which frame is stored:
    uint8_t* buffer = getFrameBuffer(); // Simplification, but not important
    
    double rot = floor(count / 10);
        
    if (10*rot != rotation)
    {
        rotation = 10*rot;
        Ytransform = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(Ycenter, rotation, 1.0);
        UVtransform = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(UVcenter, rotation, 1.0);
    }

        
    cv::Mat Y(Ysize.height, Ysize.width, CV_8UC1, buffer);
    cv::Mat U(UVsize.height, UVsize.width, CV_8UC1, buffer + Uoffset);
    cv::Mat V(UVsize.height, UVsize.width, CV_8UC1, buffer + Voffset);
        

    cv::warpAffine(Y, Y, Ytransform, Ysize);
    cv::warpAffine(U, U, UVtransform, UVsize);
    cv::warpAffine(V, V, UVtransform, UVsize);

    sendFrameToEncoder(buffer); // Also a simplification, also not important as far as i know
}
```

Where `height`, `width` are the height and width of the video frame.

However, this produces wierd, warped images. Something is clearly rotated, but not the correctly.

rotation = 0 produces:
[image: Non-rotated image]

rotation = 10 produces:
[image: "Rotated" 10 degrees]

rotation = 20 produces:
[image: "Rotated" 20 degrees]

rotation = 30 produces:
[image: "Rotated" 30 degrees]

So, it clearly isn't working correctly. Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

I'm using OpenCV version 4.5.1
On a Raspberry Pi Zero W running Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye

Comment: converting yuv to bgr and then applying rotation is an option for you ? because yuv is different than you think

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Manual conversion is probably too computationally expensive. I'm already pushing the limits in terms of fps. Either the camera output must be BGR (which I don't know how to do), or I have to rotate the yuv formatted data. What do you mean by yuv is different than I think?